# calling a payable function sending a custom amount

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation

Lets supose i got a contract named `Contract` (already an instance).
And this contract got a method/function named `function` with the `payable` clause.

This method gets the address of the caller and the amount paid to do some stuff.

I've tried calling it by: `Contract.function.value(x)(arguments)` but it throws me `TypeError: 'value' is not a function`.

How can i call this contract and send (as example) 5 ether to this function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

New way:

```
Contract.function({from:"address goes here", value:"amount goes here"})
```

And that's the way to do it.